# php array to javascript object

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have some case like this:

I have json data:

```
[{
        "1377412272": {
            "user_id": "1374050643",
            "date": "2013-08-24",
            "ip": "::1"
        }
    },
    {
        "1377412279": {
            "user_id": "1374050643",
            "date": "2013-08-25",
            "ip": "::1"
        }
    }
    , {
        "1377412287": {
            "user_id": "1377346094",
            "date": "2013-08-25",
            "ip": "::1"
        }
    }, {
        "1377413058": {
            "user_id": "1374050643",
            "date": "2013-08-25",
            "ip": "::1"
        }
    },
    {
        "1377413069": {
            "user_id": "1377346094",
            "date": "2013-08-25",
            "ip": "::1"
        }
    }
    , {
        "1377413074": {
            "user_id": "1377346094",
            "date": "2013-08-25",
            "ip": "::1"
        }
    },
    {
        "1377413079": {
            "user_id": "1377346094",
            "date": "2013-08-25",
            "ip": "::1"
        }
    }
]
```

An then, I have convert to array PHP

```
$newArr = array();
        foreach ($view['con'] as $key => $value) {
            foreach ($value as $k => $v) { 
                if (isset($newArr[$v['user_id']][$v['date']])) {
                    $newArr[$v['user_id']][$v['date']]++;
                } 
                else
                    $newArr[$v['user_id']][$v['date']] = 1; 
                $newArr[$v['user_id']][$v['date']] = isset($newArr[$v['user_id']][$v['date']]) ? $newArr[$v['user_id']][$v['date']]++ : 1;
            }
        }
```

Script above have result in json_encode with structure like this:

```
Array
( 
    [A] => Array
        (
            [2013-08-24] => 1
            [2013-08-25] => 2
        )

    [B] => Array
        (
            [2013-08-25] => 4
        )

)
```

and finally, I  want it to be javascript object

```
[
  ["date","A","B"],
  [2013-08-24,1,0],
  [2013-08-25,2,4]
]
```

How to make it?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you need to code everything manually.
One (not too simple) solution is this:

```
<?php
$ori_list = array(
    'A'=> array(
        '2013-08-24' => 1,
        '2013-08-25' => 2,
    ),
    'B'=> array(
        '2013-08-24' => 3,
    ),
);

$modif_list = array();

// prepare the header
$header = array('date');
foreach($ori_list as $key=>$val){
    if(!array_key_exists($key, $header)){
        $header[] = $key;
    }
}
$modif_list[] = $header;

// prepare the date_list
$date_list = array();
foreach($ori_list as $key=>$val){
    foreach($val as $date=>$num){
        // add the initial row for every date
        $registered = false;
        foreach($date_list as $date_row){
            if($date_row[0] == $date){
                $registered = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!$registered){
            $date_row = array($date);
            for($i=0; $i<count($header)-1; $i++){
                $date_row[] = 0;
            }
            $date_list[] = $date_row;
        }
        // put the right value to the right row
        $first_index = 0;
        $second_index = 0;
        for($i=1; $i<count($header); $i++){
            if($header[$i] == $key){
                $second_index = $i;
                break;
            }
        }
        for($i=0; $i<count($date_list); $i++){
            if($date == $date_list[$i][0]){
                $first_index = $i;
                break;
            }
        }
        $date_list[$first_index][$second_index] = $num;
    }
}
$modif_list[] = $date_list;

echo 'The PHP';
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($modif_list);
echo '</pre>';

echo 'The JSON';
echo '<pre>';
echo json_encode($modif_list);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

The code will produce something like this (which I hope is what you want):

```
The PHP
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "date"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "A"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "B"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2013-08-24"
      [1]=>
      int(1)
      [2]=>
      int(3)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "2013-08-25"
      [1]=>
      int(2)
      [2]=>
      int(0)
    }
  }
}
The JSON
[["date","A","B"],[["2013-08-24",1,3],["2013-08-25",2,0]]]
```

Comment: @goFrendiAsgrard great, this what I want.. +1

Answer (score 1):

To get output like this yo should do

```
$countArr = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value)
{
    foreach ($value as $k => $v)
    {
        if (isset($countArr[$v['date']][$v['user_id']]))
        {
            $countArr[$v['date']][$v['user_id']]++;
        }
        else
        {
            $countArr[$v['date']][$v['user_id']] = 1;
        }
    }
}
$newArr = array();
foreach ($countArr as $date => $val)
{
    $row = array($date);
    $newArr[] = array_merge(array($date), array_values($val));
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArr);
echo json_encode($newArr)
```

If you print out $newArr it will look like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-08-24
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2013-08-25
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 4
        )

)
```

json_encode will output

```
[["2013-08-24",1],["2013-08-25",2,4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP

```
$arr = array("id"=>"1");
json_encode($arr);
```

Javascript + PHP

```
var json = jQuery.parseJSON(<?=$arr?>);
var id = json.id;
```

Comment: it's not work..
I just want to make

Array
( 
    [A] => Array
        (
            [2013-08-24] => 1
            [2013-08-25] => 2
        )

    [B] => Array
        (
            [2013-08-25] => 4
        )

)

Tobe 

[
  ["date","A","B"],
  [2013-08-24,1,0],
  [2013-08-25,2,4]
]

Answer (score 0):

In php, lets call it **array.php**:

```
// Your final statment of your array.php script must be an echo statment to send the array to jQuery
$ar = array('item1' => 'value1');
$ret_val['a'] = $ar;
echo json_encode($ret_val);
```

In jQuery (for example, in the callback of `$.post`, but you can use `$.ajax` as well)

```
$.post("/path/to/array.php,

    null, // not passing any values to array.php

    function(data) {
        console.log (data.a.item1); // writes 'value1' to the console

        // (note that the 'a' in data.a.item1 in jQuery is the same as the 'a' in $ret_val in PHP)

    },

    "json");    
}
```

Then you deal with the return value anyway you like, including creating the final object you seek.

Comment: FYI, the `data` argument of `$.post` is optional, so you don't need to pass that `null` there. Also, for this use case `$.get` is preferable.

Comment: thanks gresso, but it's not seems like I want, 
I have convert array php to json_encode:
[code]
{"1374050643":{"2013-08-24":1,"2013-08-25":2},"1377346094":{"2013-08-25":4}}
[/code]

And I want make it tobe 
[code]
[
  ["date","A","B"],
  [2013-08-24,1,0],
  [2013-08-25,2,4]
]
[/code]

Can you help me??

Comment: Just make sure your last statement in your php file is **echo json_encode** as I have shown you and you get everything working.  Read the comments in the code, it will help. If you already have the json_encode done, then just echo it in our final statement of your script.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
$newArray = array
( 
    "A" => array
        (
            "2013-08-24" => 1,
            "2013-08-25" => 2
        ),

    "B" => array
        (
            "2013-08-25" => 4
        )

);

$uids=array();
$da = array();

foreach($na as $uid => $value)
{
    $uids[] = $uid;     
    foreach($value as $date => $count)
    {
        $da[$date][$uid]=$count;
    }
}


$ra = array(array("date"));

foreach($uids as $uid)
{
    $ra[0][] = $uid;
}
$i = 1;
foreach($da as $date => $value)
{
    $ra[$i][] = $date;
    foreach($uids as $uid)
    {
        if(array_key_exists($uid,$value))
        {
            $ra[$i][] = $value[$uid];
        }
        else
        {
            $ra[$i][] = 0;
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
print(json_encode($ra));
```

Output:

`[["date","A","B"],["2013-08-24",1,0],["2013-08-25",2,4]]`